# Unity Android Plugin Activity not Found

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I'm currently trying to implement a notification system for an android game and need to open the app's native settings to help the user reenable the notification, when previosly turned off. I wrote a small java class:

```
package com.example.plugin;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.content.*;
import android.provider.Settings;

public class NotificationPlugin {
    public void openSettings(Activity unityActivity) {
        Intent i = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_SETTINGS,
            Uri.parse("package:" + unityActivity.getPackageName()));

        unityActivity.startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

I added these lines to the custom AndroidManifest.xml in unity.

```
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.settings.APPLICATION_SETTINGS" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

And i'm accessing the method in a c# wrapper class with this method.

```
public static void OpenNotificationSettings() {
    AndroidJavaClass unityPlayer = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer");
    unityActivity = unityPlayer.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");
    
    pluginClass = new AndroidJavaClass(pluginName);
    pluginClass.Call("openSettings", unityActivity);
}
```

The variable `pluginName` is a constant string, containing the fully quialified package name of the plugin class.

Using logcat i can see the follwing exception when trying to execute this:

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent
```

Since i have no real experiences with either android nor using plugins in unity, i don't know what to do with the exception and where the issue in all of these layers lies.
Can anyone tell me how to fix this issue?

PS: I know that i could probably have done this without a plugin, but there are other methods in the plugin, that i need and i wanted to have all native android related code packed into one plugin.

Comment: Please provide your entire java class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original problem was that your unity activity class wasn't in a package, but you were trying to load it as if it was in a package. Replace your code with this:

```
package com.example.plugin;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.content.*;
import android.provider.Settings;

public class NotificationPlugin {
    public void openSettings(Context context) {
        Intent i = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_SETTINGS,
            //Uri.parse("package:" + unityActivity.getPackageName()));

        context.startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

And unity part:

```
public static void OpenNotificationSettings() {
    AndroidJavaClass unityPlayer = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer");
    unityActivity = unityPlayer.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");
    
    pluginClass = new AndroidJavaClass(pluginName);
    pluginClass.CallStatic("openSettings", unityActivity);
}
```